# I am not being able to run c/c++ programs in vscode in macbook air m1

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

[image]Everytime i try to run a program it says launch program does not exist [image]here is my json file

I thought it will run but it doesnt I even followed some solutions but they didnt work i have homebrew installed and all the neccesary extensions in vscode.

Comment: You already ran the program with the command in the first image. `Hello world!` seems to be its output.

Comment: Please don't show images of text. Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions. Like the code, the `launch.json` file, the contents of the terminal and output panes, and most importantly the problems pane which seems to have one problem in it.

Comment: Well, did you *build* a program called "no1_2"? By the looks of it, you have only built "Untitled-1", which ran successfully.

Comment: I see Untitled-1 but not no1_2, as listed by launch.json. As @user17732522 says I see that you ran the untitled program and it worked. What are you asking?

Comment: I believe the question is how to properly configure the `launch.json` file. My advice is to read the documentation here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)